# Getting the value from an HTML button using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, function, calculator

I am making a calculator, I have already created the calculator in html and css but I am trying to move forward by making the button clicks register in the display which is what my problem is right now. I am fairly new to JavaScript so if someone could point me in the right direction on how to do it or where to find the answer I would appreciate it.

This is a the portion I am working on, trying to get button '7' to register so I can do the others.

```
<div class="container-fluid calc" >
 <div class="display">
  <label type="text" id="screen">0</label>

   <div class="buttons">

     <button onClick='calculate()' id='myButton'>7</button>
     <button>8</button>
     <button>9</button>
```

Here is the JS I put together

```
function calculate(){
  var num = document.getElementById('#myButton').contentValue;
  document.getElementById('screen').innerHTML = num;
}

calculate();
```

Comment: getElementById('#myButton') should be getElementById('myButton'). # is used in JQuery functions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to update from

```
 var num = document.getElementById('#myButton').contentValue;
```

to

```
 var num = document.getElementById('myButton').innerHTML;
```

Comment: Thank you nikhil, that did it

Answer (score 4):

You should use the `.innerHTML` function instead of the `.contentValue` function to do this, also, you shouldn't use a `#` in `document.getElementById` this is used in jQuery, so just the ID is enough

```
function calculate(){
    var num = document.getElementById('myButton').innerHTML;
    document.getElementById('screen').innerHTML = num;
}

calculate();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: `#` isn't jQuery. Its a selector. You could use document.querySelector. Just to be clear. Either way +1.

Comment: @AtheistP3ace Thanks for that, honestly did not know that. Learning new stuff every day

Comment: Well then, knowledge has been spread in numerous directions this day! =]

Comment: @AtheistP3ace It seems like it has! :))

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I tried that but its not registering on the screen, It stays blank. Is there another way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Update

```
function calculate(){
  var num = document.getElementById('#myButton').contentValue;
  document.getElementById('screen').innerHTML = num;
}
```

to

```
function calculate(){
  var num = document.getElementById('myButton').innerText;
  document.getElementById('screen').innerText = num;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is you can is data attribute like this :

```
<button onClick='calculate()' id='myButton' data-value="7">7</button>
```

and get it like this :

```
$("#myButton").attr("data-value");
```